# What happens when wrong dataType is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, post

I perform a call

```
$.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataToPost,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus){ /*something*/ },
    failure: myHttpReqErrorHandler
  });
```

In certain cases when things goes wrong on the server I get

```
Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

type, and content is a real HTML page, and there is not much I can do about that. I want to manage this case on JavaScript, but when this happens no callback is called on jQuery side (neither success nor failure).

Is there a further parameter to pass to `ajax` to handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error handler is `error: function(){}`

```
error: myHttpReqErrorHandler
```

It will throw a parse error(`parsererror`) if the content is not a parsable json format.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hen2b/)